# Spacing between poem title and poem text

Tags: spacing, book-design, poetry

I'm writing a book of poems using the `book` class. Most of the poems are pretty short and I'm only putting 1 or 2 poems on each page. The problem I'm having is that latex is putting a large space between the poem title and the poem. How do I prevent this from happening? I know some of you may be tempted to recommend that I use the `memoir` class instead, but I've already done so much work in the book class, so I'd prefer to just keep using the `book` class. Next time I'll try the `memoir` class.

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{Lamp}
\begin{verse}
The lamp is nice\\
The lamp is cool\\
Blah diddy blah\\
The lamp turns blue
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default page formatting includes the `flushbottom` directive, which makes text end at the same place (vertically) on each page and can result in excessively large vertical spacings. This not sensible for verse, and you can use the `raggedbottom` directive instead, which will not stretch vertical skips.

Answer (score 2):

In according to the manual, you have to change the `\afterpoemtitleskip` length:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{verse}
\setlength{\afterpoemtitleskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\poemtitle{Lamp}
\begin{verse}
The lamp is nice\\
The lamp is cool\\
Blah diddy blah\\
The lamp turns blue
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link to the manual?

Comment: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf or `texdoc verse` from command line

Comment: Actually, that doesn't quite work for me. It only fixes some of the poems, but for others there is still too much space between the title and the poem. I tried using negative numbers (-3cm), but then some of the poems have negative spacing while others are perfect. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't know. You must write a better MWE.

Comment: Perhaps add `\raggedbottom` in your preamble, instead of the default `\flushbottom`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! that totally worked! If you retype this as an answer, I will give you a check mark.